# Recommended Device - react-native for Android

Tags: android, react-native

I searched all over the documentation but couldn't find a recommended device for react-native android development.

It would be nice if you could pick up a phone that is 'the standard handheld' for development were all features are thoroughly tested on.

Can anyone point me to some information or even recommend a well supported device?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would be nice to get a comment with the downvote.
That way I could correct the error you might've perceived?

Answer (score 1):

The Nexus 5X is the phone you are looking for =)

Comment: Why that and not another phone?

Comment: It's powerfull, it's google (like android), and easy to manage (dev settings all of that. I like to work on this phone and i tried like 20/25 phones for the work)

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that there is one device which is the "perfect" one for testing Android. Lets not forget that Android runs on more than 10k+ different devices so every device show your application different. Also some mobile companies has an addition to the Android software.

When developing myself a Android application I found out that on some devices I have some bugs which on other there is not a problem.

What I am trying to do when I am testing on Android is to have different devices with different resolutions and also with different Android versions but still, this cannot cover everything you need from my point of view. Also before releasing an application, I am making a group of beta testers with different people and this is how I found out most of my errors.

Hope it helped just a bit!

Comment: thanks for the reply - I am aware that there are a lot of android devices, hence my question. Your second paragraph also supports my point: there are quite some differences between the devices. Therefore it would be nice to know if the react-native team has a recommendation for a specific device with a specific version of android that has proven to be reliable and has the least amount of issues.

thanks

Comment: On the React-Native documentation, the tutorial shows the Android Studio Emulator but not sure if this is the "recommended" one. I use for example Genymotion. Not sure how much helps you this info but hope at least a bit.

Comment: Nope, sorry that doesn't do it for me - I'm asking for an actual physical phone.

Thanks anyways